# Asp.net mvc bundle. Combining works well. But compressing and minifying not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

All of my javascript and css combined. But when i'am looking they arent minified. I dont know why.

My bundle is shown below:

```
         bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/grid.locale-tr.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/messages_tr.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.form.js"
           )
       );
        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/mainjs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/superfish.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
            "~/Scripts/touchTouch.jquery.js"
           )
       );

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/allcss").Include(
           "~/Content/Css/bootstrap*",
           "~/Content/Css/opa-icons.css",
           "~/Content/Css/charisma-app.css",
           "~/Content/Css/ui.jqgrid.css",
           "~/Content/Css/jquery-ui.css"
           )
       );

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/maincss").Include(
           "~/Content/Css/bootstrap.css",
           "~/Content/Css/responsive.css",
           "~/Content/Css/style.css",
           "~/Content/Css/touchTouch.css",
           "~/Content/Css/kwicks-slider.css"
           )
       );
```

My global asax shown in below:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
#if DEBUG
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
                    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());
    }
```

And:

```
 @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mainjs")
 @System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/maincss")
```

Comment: Are you in Debug mode? What is the output HTML for script references?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They're not minified because you're using a Bundle instead of a ScriptBundle. A **Bundle** only bundles them (hey, what's in a word :) ) A **ScriptBundle** bundles and minifies.

Answer (score 7):

They are not minified cause you're probably in `DEBUG` mode.

try to set this

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

and see what happens.